# Error when opening heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have deployed my rails app to heroku, and am now trying to open it with "heroku open", however i get the error that "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.". These are the logs:

```
2017-12-26T18:40:16.269452+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-12-26T18:40:16.261939+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2017-12-26T18:40:16.261951+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2017-12-26T18:40:16.269455+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2017-12-26T18:40:16.261978+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-12-26T18:40:16.269456+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-12-26T18:40:16.269455+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-12-26T18:40:16.372189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-12-26T18:40:16.359435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-26T18:40:16.911232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-stream-77985.herokuapp.com request_id=60caaad5-f16e-4443-8b8f-e278d41d966d fwd="2.104.49.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-12-26T18:40:57.610077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-stream-77985.herokuapp.com request_id=9b3b9601-d003-49fd-8661-fd4494f84632 fwd="2.104.49.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-12-26T18:45:46.508705+00:00 heroku[run.1739]: Awaiting client
2017-12-26T18:45:46.560426+00:00 heroku[run.1739]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2017-12-26T18:45:46.570612+00:00 heroku[run.1739]: State changed from starting to up
2017-12-26T18:45:42.507797+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by user <mymail>@gmail.com
2017-12-26T18:45:53.393255+00:00 heroku[run.1739]: Process exited with status 0
2017-12-26T18:45:53.406858+00:00 heroku[run.1739]: State changed from up to complete
2017-12-26T18:46:09.405442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-stream-77985.herokuapp.com request_id=e38838f5-294c-45eb-a936-81f89e8fed2d fwd="2.104.49.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: I see `rails db:migrate` in there. That seems like a strange command to run when starting your application… how and why are you running that command?

Comment: See i don't know. I have only run that command before pushing the app to heroic. I can't recall doing it anywhere else